# android image.setImageResource(..) causes text on button to dissappear

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button and an image object defined in a TableLayout in my xml file as:

```
    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.99"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="1sp"
                    android:text="@string/buttonNext"/>
    <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33" 
                    android:src="@drawable/sixthstring"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/chart_description"/>
```

There is an OnClickListener hooked to the next button and it all worked fine.

I created an OnClickListener for the imageView and put in the following code:

```
  imgChart.setOnClickListener(onChartClick);
```

.
.
.

```
  private OnClickListener onChartClick = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            imgChart.setImageResource(R.drawable.newPngImage);
        }
     };
```

The app works well, even when I click the image and retrieve the new image.  However, if the phone sleeps and then returns or if I click the menu button (both causing a redraw?) the *text* of the *next* button disappears (the image in the imageView is fine and the button itself is still there) - weird.

If I comment out the setImageResource method, it all works fine again.

Answer (score 3):

Have exactly the same problem with you Tony.
I use "`setImageDrawable`" instead and everything is still on their position, works perfect!

Comment: An reference for others who have the same issue. It seems to happen on 4.1.1. If you have a `TableLayout` and an `ImageView` in your layout xml file. Call `ImageView.setImageResource` will cause `TableLayout` dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setBackgroundResource(id)` instead of  `setImageResource(id)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this also and the button text still disappears.  In fact, with that method the new image does not show, instead the old image remains.